# How do I test private methods in Rust?

Tags: testing, rust

How do I test private methods in Rust? I didn't find any information about it. There's no information in the documentation either.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

When using `#[test]`, there’s nothing special about private or public methods—you’re just writing perfectly normal functions that can access anything they can access.

```
fn private_function() {
}

#[test]
fn test_private_function() {
    private_function()
}
```

External tests, such as `tests/*.rs` and `examples/*.rs` if you’re using Cargo, or doc tests, do not get access to private members; nor should they: such tests are designed to be public API tests, not to be dealing with implementation details.

Comment: External tests should absolutely be allowed acces to private parts, because 1) You might need access to private parts in order to reliably trigger all code paths through the public API. For example, there might be an internal threshold that when reached triggers different code path. You might also need failure injection or internal details to trigger edge cases. 2) Access to private parts can provide better diagnostic for when tests fail - you can insert internal info into panic message etc...

Comment: Diagnostics: that’s what `std::fmt::Debug` is for. For the rest, I stand by my position that external tests should not have access to private details. External tests are not appropriate for the situation you describe—that’s what internal unit tests are for.

Comment: `fmt::Debug` is too coarse-grained in some situations - for example, you might not want print details about a whole huge data structure when you're only after a specific bit. Anyway, is it appropriate for internal test to also setup a realistic use case of the public API? If not, that won't do, since I need to do just that. If yes, then alright I'm happy to all it and internal test, although at that point the distinction is kind of pointeless? The core issue is that no matter how hard you try, the implementation details always affect interface in some way, there's no way around it.

Comment: Black-and-white idealism fails at multi-objective optimization. Ideally, external tests should not access the private internals of an application. But there are competing ideals to balance against. Sometimes the most practical way to get good test coverage is by directly digging in and tweaking something private. Sure, you could add extra complexity to your code to make this unnecessary, but that has a cost. It's useful to have the flexibility to make these decisions on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Here's why tests need access to private internals. If the above argument is not terribly convincing: Imagine I am writing an "object" which is a container for some other "thing". I might want to be able to "push" data into that thing, and somehow "get data back out", but I might not want to expose "how much stuff is in there" or anything to do with internal implementation details. Lots of things are like this. You wrap a std::container of some kind, and don't expose `.len()`. For testing however, I want to query `.len()` because I might put some data in, and want to check that it's there.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if this issue is still open for you, but I found some documentation about it :

[Test Organization](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html#testing-private-functions)

What I retained from it is that you *can* test private method but *only* if the test can see it (i.e. they are in the same scope), since tests follow the visibility rules as any other function.

Here is a working example :

```
pub fn add_two(a: i32) -> i32 {
    internal_adder(a, 2)
}

fn internal_adder(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    a + b
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn internal() {
        assert_eq!(4, internal_adder(2, 2));
    }
}
```

All in all, please remember that the debate wether private methods should or should not be tested is still open within the test community. Both sides have valid argument and the correct answer only relies on you, your vision on testing procedure and the context of your project.

Comment: I have a question, this code leads to a warning: `warning: function is never used: `internal_adder``, but the `internal_adder` function is called in the `internal` function. Is it because the test code is dead code? I didn't find any documentation describing this. I know that adding `pub` will remove this warning, which is somewhat similar to `export` in other programming languages.

Comment: @liby the `internal` function isn't part of the final executable it's part of test which is what you are specifying when you write `#[cfg(test)]`. when you use `cargo run` or `cargo build` the tests are neither run nor included in the executable. so the compiler says `internal_adder` has not been used.

Answer (score 0):

A work around that is not mentioned above, is to write tests for private methods within a public method in the implementation, then call that method in tests .... not ideal I know.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dd2375c055f0689431ffdf20d10cdf40

```
mod x_mod {

pub struct MyStruct;

impl MyStruct {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        MyStruct
    }
    fn private_method(&self, x: u8) -> u8 {
        x + 1
    }
    pub fn pub_method(&self, x: u8) -> u8 {
        x + 1
    }
    
    pub fn pub_method_tests_priv_method(&self, x: u8) -> u8 {
        self.private_method(1)
    }
}
}

// NOTE: these tests could be in a different location or file and 2 and
// 3 would still pass

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
use super::*;

#[test]
fn private_method_test() {
    let m = x_mod::MyStruct::new();
    //assert_eq!(m.private_method(1), 2); // Fail if uncommented
}

#[test]
fn pub_method_test() {
    let m = x_mod::MyStruct::new();
    assert_eq!(m.pub_method(1), 2);
}

#[test]
fn pub_method_tests_priv() {
    let m = x_mod::MyStruct::new();
    assert_eq!(m.pub_method_tests_priv_method(1), 2);
}
}
```

Comment: That is unnecessary. Rust allows you to test private methods directly:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=743c2b7e1b9c9beb244604bad5760a58

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have fixed the answer, please review when you get the chance.